# How to make any SVG image grayscaled using css?

Tags: html, css, image, svg, grayscale

I have some images with svg extension. I need to get those images in grayscale mode. Is it possible to do it only using css or whatever I can do with files or the `<svg>` tag itself? I don't want to use online tools for this convert, I need the pure styling "tools", like html css js. I have read that adding classes to `<img>` tag might be helpful. By the way, I need it in its original quality, so just making it gray-colored is the only objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `<img>` and CSS function `grayscale()`.

```
<img src="img.svg" style="filter: grayscale(1);"/>
```

Comment: Won't it affect on the quality? and does it clearly fill the image in gray? I mean no problems with background color etc.

Comment: It won't affect on the quality. It only affect on the img tag so if you want also background-color on img then you must add it as child of additional div.